# How to reuse the test classes in one project in the main application of another project in Java

Tags: java, maven

I have a case were I need to reuse the some of the classes located in *src/test/java* of my first project in the main application of another project. Currently I have the artifactId-version-tests.jar created for the first project and have added the below dependency in the pom xml file of my second project.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>firstproject</groupId>
  <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
  <version>version</version>
  <type>test-jar</type>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

With this even though I am able to run my second project locally, while packaging (using the mvn package) the artifactId-version-tests.jar is not getting added to the lib directory and hence my application is throwing a class not found exception when running in a different system.

Can anyone suggest a solution for this issue. How can I use this artifactId-version-tests.jar from my first project to be reused in my second project.

Answer (score 3):

If you need these classes in more than one project, create a separate project or module for them.

Then you can use it like any other dependency.